# How Can I validate byte data before converting it into PDF?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, xss, veracode

I am using REST WebService which returns stream of byte data.
I use this byte data to create a PDF file. Now I am not validating this byte data before converting it to PDF which is shown as security concern in Veracode  tool. How Can I make it secure?
Below is the code that I am using for converting the byte data to pdf file:

```
    byte[] pdfBytes = bytes from WS
    if (null != pdfBytes) {
        resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
        resp.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        resp.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        resp.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store,no-cache");
        resp.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=" + StringUtils.escapeCarriageReturns(statementCode + acctNumber, false));
        ***resp.getOutputStream().write(pdfBytes);***
        resp.getOutputStream().flush();
    }
```

In the above code I want to check before line(marked as ***) can I add something to check If the bytes contain malicious content(Cross Site link or scripts).

Comment: There are entire companies dedicated to this.  You'd have to know what is and isn't a "malicious" PDF.  In short - you can't really without integrating with a virus scan or other validation product.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there could be a way to solve it without using different application integration.